# Override default navigator.plugins

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to build an array that mimics the browsers plugin array:

```
var customPluginList = [{
name: 'Adobe Acrobat',
description: 'Adobe PDF Plug-In For Firefox and Netscape 11.0.69',
filename: 'nppdf32.dll',
version: '11.0.8.69'
}, {
name: 'Silverlight Plug-In',
description: '5.1.30514.69',
filename: 'npctrl.dll',
version: '5.1.30514.0'
});
```

When I try to loop customPluginList outputting the name field I receive `[object Object]`.

Comment: How are you outputting the object? What do you expect to see (i.e., how does `navigator.plugins` behave in the same loop)? Also, please post your loop code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your output function.

If you are trying to do so:

```
 alert(myObject);
```

`alert` will call the `toString` function which will give:

```
 [object Object]
```

So that's "normal".

If you want to you'll have to use `JSON.stringify`:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

And that works :)

**The console.log function prints the same, but on modern browser you can click it to see its content**